# app_dev.php works as expected, but app.php always gives a 503 error

Tags: symfony

Recently created a new application and bundle in Symfony. No homepage is defined, so loading `http://localhost/app_dev.php` loads the default Symfony page, and all routes work as expected when using `app_dev.php`

However, when I try to load just `http://localhost` or any of the same routes without specifying `app_dev.php` in the address, it gives the message `503 Service Unavailable`

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Im having the same issue and its definitely a server config issue - my codebase works flawlessly on other servers. The prod.log isnt being created so I dont know where to start my debugging.

Comment: @beterthanlife Sorry, don't remember how I fixed it and I'm now at a different job (and a different city). If you figure it out, please post it here and I'll mark you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the route : **localhost/app_dev.php** you have to active your **rewrite_url** and use an **.htaccess** to redirect from your root folder to **/projectRootFolder/web/**

In your routing_dev file **app/config/routing_dev.yml** remove the demo bundle and active your own route to your controller action

The 503 Service Unavailable error is an HTTP status code that means the web site's server is simply not available right now. Most of the time this is because the server is too busy or because there's maintenance being performed on it.

tyr to restart apache2 server if your are on linux `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Check logs for errors.
When You change from `app_dev.php` to `app.php` you change cache, some requirements from composer are changed .. ect. 
Best way is to start from logs if logs are empty, check if error reporting level in `php.ini` is set correctly (set it to `E_ALL`).

For example in app_dev You don't use caches (doctrine caches) - sometimes those bundles are not valid.